# FIFO inventory aging report using a single query in T-SQL

Tags: performance, t-sql, report, fifo, inventory-management

I've got an inventory transactions table :

| Product | Date | Direction | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Date 1 | IN | 3 |
| B | Date 2 | IN | 55.7 |
| A | Date 3 | OUT | 1 |
| B | Date 3 | OUT | 8 |
| B | Date 3 | IN | 2 |

I can easily get the stock for any date with the following query :

```
SELECT Product,
SUM(CASE Direction WHEN 'IN' THEN Quantity ELSE -1 * Quantity END)
FROM Transactions
WHERE Date <= '#DateValue#'
GROUP BY Product;
```

Now my purpose is to get stocks **aged** like this using the **FIFO** principle :

| Product | Total stock | 0-30 days | 31-60 days | 61-90 days | 91+ days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 34.2 | 10 | 14.2 | 7 | 3 |
| C | 25 | 20 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| D | 10 | 2 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| E | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I am using SQL Server 2016 & SSMS 18.
The solution should be **fast** as it will be working against a table with **3,000,000+ rows**.
A **single query** is preferred since it will be integrated into an ERP system.
I have yet to find a solution based on a single query after weeks of research. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL does wonders for communicating data types and indexes, if any. And the _actual execution plan_ is a great place to start with many performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: Take a look at cross tab (pivot) queries

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to do FIFO with a single query; you need a loop (even if you handle multiple rows in an iteration); after assigning each output operation to one or more input operations, you may get the result in a single query.